# Why does delay() cause my arduino to reset?

Tags: arduino, delay, arduino-uno

I am using an Arduino Uno, connected to a USB shield, a RFID shield(adafruit PN532), an LCD, EEPROM(24AA256) and a RTC module(DS1307). I will not post my code here because it is too large and it is separated in multiple files.

In my program, I realize that if my programs enters a certain functions, after entering function after function, if I use a delay() at the end of the function I am currently in, the arduino resets. An example of what I mean is below.

```
void a() { b(); }
void b() { c(); }
void c() { d(); }
void d()
{
  lcd_string("Testing", 0x80);
  delay(2000);      <---- Arduino resets at the delay here
}
```

At first, I thought it was because my  dynamic memory was at 80%, and when I compiled, they said the Arduino might have some stability issues. So I modified my code such that my dynamic memory is now 57%. Problem still exist.

I thought maybe the delay() function has some overflow or something, so I tried replacing the delay with the following code.

```
unsigned long timing;

timing = millis();
timing += 2000;
while(millis() < timing);
```

The Arduino still resets.

Next, I thought maybe because my arduino is connected to my PC, some serial pin might have been causing the reset, so I used an external Power to power up the arduino and disconnected the USB. The arduino still resets.

Next, I thought maybe Timer1 might have been crashing with the delay() function, although the delay function uses Timer0 so I disabled my Timer1 . The arduino still resets.

Is there any other possibilities that I am missing out? My program storage space is at 69% which I believe shouldn't be an issue.

**Edit**

Here is my code for Timer1 ISR

```
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;
  TCNT1  = 0;
  OCR1A = 34286;// = (16*10^6) / (1*1024) - 1 (must be <65536)
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12);  
  // enable timer compare interrupt
 TIMSK1 |= (1 << TOIE1);
 triggered = 1;
}
```

Any other interrupt of flags used are in the library header files.
I am using the following external libraries
USB Host shield library 2.0
Adafruit PN532 master

Comment: Thanks for the edit. How hard would it be for you to produce a [Minimal, verifiable and reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that others can test it? does the current issue disappear if you remove something apparently unnecessary from the sketch?

Comment: Minimal is a good question. Would take me 2 hours or so, here is the link to my code. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzCRu6FuIiXJS1ZxVUhrT2N2ME0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, just for the sake of clarity, when you say that you 'disabled your Timer1', you mean that none of those lines is ever executed, aka you commented out that code?

Comment: I tried removing a lot of unnecessary stuff from the sketch already, not sure if that is all, but as far as I am working on, Majority of it is needed.

The problem is in the administrator.cpp file, change_password() function. It is accessed from the main loop by entering the admin_login() function, same file, and then the admin_menu() function, same file, when successfully authenticated.

Comment: Yes, I commented it out. Both the ISR and the initialization

Comment: Just an extra note, any delay before the last delay does not cause any reset.

Comment: There are two limits: FLASH and RAM. 
Missing RAM is causing "instability". Is that what you report as `program storage space is at 69% ` ?
What happens if you simply add a local variable in function `void d();`
Which size of a byte array is possibble?

Comment: Well, to produce a *minimal* example perhaps the best idea is to start with an empty sketch and start adding features, first and foremost a call to `delay()` .. and see at which point it crashes.

Comment: I believe program storage is FLASH. They only report that instability may occur when my dynamic memory, which i believe is the RAM, has less than 512 bytes free.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I have been doing that for 2 days already, haven't the slightest clue. In the change_password function, the function enter_password is called twice. If i put the code from the enter_password function into the change_password function rather than calling it as a function, the arduino doesn't reset. But I still face the problem at other sections of the sketch.

Comment: one less call function is one less data-frame on the stack, is there a way to check amount of free memory on Arduino at runtime?

Comment: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvailableMemory
I used the following library above, as i progressed through my functions, I constantly had more than 700 bytes available.

Comment: Any news? did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A little sample to come close to RAM corruption ...

```
#define MEM_PER_LEVEL 50
#define TRY_TO_SURVIVE 10
void KillMe(int level) {
   byte dummy[MEM_PER_LEVEL];
   for ( byte  i = 0; i < MEM_PER_LEVEL; i++)
      dummy[i]= i;
   Serial.println(level);
   delay(1000);  // not sure why this would hurt more than others
   if (level < TRY_TO_SURVIVE) KillMe(level+1);
   for ( byte  i = 0; i < MEM_PER_LEVEL; i++) {
       if (dummy[i] != i) {
           Serial.println(F("corruption happened")); 
           while(1) {} // HALT
       }

  }
   if (level == 0) 
   Serial.println(F("survived"));
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  KillMe(0);
}

void loop() { }
```

Comment: I tried your code a few times, had no problem on my arduino. I had to change the TRY_TO_SURVIVE to 30. When I did, the arduino restart once and on the second time, it hanged. When It restart, the amount of RAM available was less than 200. However when I tested my code, I had slightly more than 700 bytes free. So I doubt RAM corruption was the issue with the reset.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - wherever I put a delay in my setup function the Arduino would restart.

For me, the problem was an instance of SoftwareSerial with invalid pin numbers.

```
SoftwareSerial mySerial(30, 31);
```

Anyone else landing on this question should check their pin numbers are appropriate for the board they're targeting.  Not sure why the crash only happens if a delay is called, would be interested if anyone has insight into this!